# Aptana 3 plugin for eclipse and publish

Tags: eclipse, aptana, sftp

What I am after is the ability to right click on an edited file and send it to either an SFTP site or a mapped location from within Eclipse so if there is another plugin besides Aptana which allows me to do that it would work as well.

I have been using the Aptana 2 plugin with Eclipse for a long time for its ability to push files to either a server (via SFTP) or mapped drive.
I just updated my Eclipse install to Juno and Aptana 2 will no longer install due to changes in Eclipse.

I then installed Aptana 3 and am not able to set up publish options for my projects.

I have seen the wiki on the Aptana site which tells you to use the App Explorer then click the left button on the toolbar to set deployment options.
Unfortunately in eclipse (at least my install) the left button does nothing.
I have also tried right clicking the project and choosing publish (no options there either)
Is this broken in the plugin but working in Studio?

I have tried Remote system explorer as well but I don't want to edit remote files, I want to edit locally commit to source when ready and deploy to remote site.

PS
I had installed Aptana 3 previously in Eclipse Indigo but then removed it and reverted to 2.0 due to the same issue but that doesn't seem to be an option now due to the changes in Juno.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I can't seem to find an answer in Google or here.

Thanks.

Comment: Found an open bug on the Aptana support site.
Root of the issue seems to be with Eclipse but there is a patch posted on the bug thread which corrected it

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4998

Answer (score 2):

Found an open bug on the Aptana support site. Root of the issue seems to be with Eclipse but there is a patch posted on the bug thread which corrected it [jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4998](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4998)